# printer problem since upgrade

Tags: updates, printing

I am new to Linux, but I have been using computers for many years. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a Dell Dimension E520 Dual partition with windows. Connected to an Epson NX400 via USB cable.

The printer worked perfectly before the last automatic software update. Now it will not print. I tried following another help page's instructions about printer issues. I have cleared the print queue, and removed the printer icons, shut down, removed the USB cable, turned the computer back on reconnected the printer, which was recognized but it still will not function, and its icon does not appear in the printer list.

The printer trouble shooter outputted the following; "su -c 'journalctl -u cups.service --since="None" --until="2016-10-14 05:02:41"' > troubleshoot-logs.txt" which I ran in the terminal as administrator but I get "su Authentication failure" multiple times. I do not yet understand Linux terminal enough to tweak the command.

The printers-localhost window indicates there are no printers configured yet.

** How do I determine what should be added in the "Enter Device URI" field?

The printer was recognized automatically when Ubuntu was installed.

** Is there any way to have it recognized automatically again?

I believe that possibly part of the problem may be; there was an executable file called command2eps and now the system is looking for looking for a file called command2epson after the update. I am not sure how to proceed. When the printer is connected a message appears "Epson Stylus Printer Connected." But it still does not appear in the installed printer icons.

The printer still works fine in the Windows partition.

Please help me to get the printer reinstalled and working again in Ubuntu.

Thanks! :)

Comment: What is the printer?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a Dell Dimension E520 Dual partition with windows. Connected to an Epson NX400 Printer  via USB cable.

Comment: Epson Stylus NX400

Comment: Try this command instead: `sudo journalctl -u cups.service > troubleshoot-logs.txt`, and [edit] the contents of `troubleshoot-logs.txt` into your answer if it's short, otherwise paste it at http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and [edit] the provided link into your question.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23325893/

Answer (score 0):

Proprietary drivers are often required for Epson printers.

Epson provides full Linux support for Epson Stylus NX400. Go to the [downloads page](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/), search using your model name and select Linux as the OS, download and install the proprietary drivers.

1. Preliminary step: According to Epson, *in order to install these drivers, you need to install LSB package (version 3.2 or later) beforehand*. Do so in terminal with `sudo apt install lsb` (starting with 16.04 `apt` can and should be used instead of `apt-get`)
2. Download the Printer Driver and Printer Utility Software:

   epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.9-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb

   epson-printer-utility_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb

Install in that order. .deb files can be easily installed just by double-clicking. It opens with the default software center.

3. Scanner: Download, extract and run the installer script for [Image Scan! for Linux](http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan_c.php?version=1.0.2). Open the terminal in the extracted folder and do `sudo ./install.sh`. Alternative it should be possible to install it using the `iscan-data_1.37.0-3_all.deb` file inside the DATA folder.

Comment: my system is 32 bits, I see the drivers you are pointing at contain the phrase "amd64" will this be a problem?

Comment: Have installed LSB package.  I went to the downloads page and searched both for Epson Stylus NX400 + Linux, and Epson NX400 + Linux. Both resulted in zero results.

Comment: There is a sytem problem:

Comment: System program problem detected

Sorry, Ubuntu 16.04 has experuenced an internal error.

ExecutablePath
   /urs/lib/i385-lunux-gnu/cups-pk-helper-mechanism
Package
   cups-pk-helper 0.2.5-2ubuntu2
Problem type 
   crash
Title
   cups-pk-helper-mechanosm crashed with signal 5 in g_variant_new_va()
ApportVersion
   2.20.1-Oubuntu2.1
Architecture
   i386

... too much to type     cc: @CelticWarrior   ... I have to go away for 5 days will continue upon my return.

Comment: Yes, use the 32-bit versions (i386). I assumed you had a 64-bit OS in a 64-bit capable hardware, even in a +10 years old one.